running normal java non-spark application in spark cluster
I want to run/execute a normal java application which connects to teradata database.
I would like to run this java app in spark cluster although my java app is non-spark.
Questions are as follows

Is it ok to run normal java app in spark cluster.
when i manually ssh into one of the node of the cluster and run java app like this it runs without issue

java -jar TeradataConnection.jar -conn_file=DB_TERADATA.properties 
-update=" INSERT INTO GRP.HDP SELECT * FROM GRP.HDP_STG "

But when i execute java app in dataproc(spark) cluster it throws error
"Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Expected IV length of 12 but was 16"

this is what i use to run the app in dataproc cluster
QUERY="INSERT INTO GRP.HDP SELECT * FROM GRP.HDP_STG"
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --project=prj1 --cluster=drpc_cluster --region=$DPRC_REGION --class=bin.TDQueryShell --jars=gs://jars/TeradataConnection.jar 
--files=teradata_utils/DB_TERADATA.properties 
--properties=spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1,spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.master=yarn,spark.executor.memory=1G,spark.driver.memory=1G,
spark.executor.instances=1 
-- -conn_file=DB_TERADATA.properties -update="$QUERY"
why is same jar running ok but giving "Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Expected IV length of 12 but was 16" error when run in spark cluster
I tried running a java non-spark jar in dataproc cluster. It failed.
I think it should have been succeeded if while running normally it is succeeding

The error "InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Expected IV length of 12 but was 16" is a known incompatibilty between old versions of the Teradata JDBC Driver and certain Java Security Providers that require 12-byte IVs and do not permit 16-byte IVs.
Teradata JDBC Driver 17.10.00.23 and later include the change JDBC-191817 "Implement new QOP GCM96". This change depends on the database change TDGSS DR 196439 "New Qop AES-GCM96 to supersede AES-GCM and AES-AEADGCM" which is available in Teradata database 17.20 and later.
